# Where is customer object saved in parse / stripe

Tags: parse-platform, stripe-payments

I was able to successfully create a customer object using Parse Cloud module.  Now that this customer object is created, how do I get the customer id that it should be returning?  Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createCustomer", function(request, response) {    
  Stripe.Customers.create({
        account_balance: 0,
        email: request.params.email,
        description: 'new stripe user',
        metadata: {
           name: request.params.name,
           userId: request.params.objectId, // e.g PFUser object ID
           createWithCard: false
           }
         }, {
            success: function(httpResponse) {
                 response.success("success");
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
                 console.log(httpResponse);
                 response.error("Cannot create a new customer.");
             }
      });
```

});

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732026/creating-a-stripe-customer-using-parse     In this response, where is customerId being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The httpResponse actually returns the entire customer. If you just want the customer ID just use this:

```
httpResponse["id"]
```

If you just want to return the entire customer to whatever called the function simply return it in the response.success:

```
response.success(httpResponse);
```